# how to create web conference service? like Trueconf

Tags: web, video-streaming

I need create app like

```
trueconf
```

to link 45 users in one video conference 
how to make it? where can I start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can WebRTC, Javascript, Okta and JSON to build your own chat room and then expand off of that. There are multiple tutorials out there that can help get you started.

https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-video-chat-service-with-javascript-webrtc-and-okta

https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-10-21-building-a-webrtc-video-and-voice-chat-application/